# Having issues with css div heights percentages

Tags: php, html, css

Despite of other people having the same issues I still couldn't get it to work, so I'll really need your help.

I'm currently writing a guestbook in php with a html-template but I have the issue that my divs don't use the min-height properties that I set if they are a percentage. I wanted to make the whole page responsive for all resolutions and window-sizes so that's why I'm trying to avoid fixed heights.

The following is my html-markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="<?=$dir_stylesheetFile?>" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

    <title><?=$GuestbookTitle ?></title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="wrap_main">

      <div class="menubar">
        <ul class="menubar_list">

          <a href="http://wikitest.gutknecht-informatik.com"> <!-- Home should always exist,
            other menubar-items can be added in MenubarHandler.php > InternLink or ExternLink -->
            <li class="menubar_item" id="int"><span id="menubar_text">Home</span></li>
          </a>
          <?=$MenuPagesString ?>
        </ul>
        <?=$MenuPagesStringExt ?>
      </div> <!-- menubar -->

      <div id="wrap_header">
        <div id="logoplacer">
          <a href="http://wikitest.gutknecht-informatik.com">
            <img id="img_logo" src="/../data/images/Logo_Guestbook.png" alt="Guestsbook Home"/>
          </a>
        </div> <!-- logoplacer -->

        <div id="profileplacer">
          <?= $ProfilePlacer ?>
        </div> <!-- profileplacer -->
      </div> <!-- wrap_header -->

      <div id="wrap_content">
        <div id="content">
          <div id="content_title">
            <h2><?=$CurrContentTitle ?></h2>
          </div> <!-- content_title -->
          <div id="content_text">
            <?=$CurrContentText ?>
          </div> <!-- content_text -->
        </div> <!-- content -->
      </div> <!-- wrap_content -->
      <div id="wrap_footer">
        © by Kathara
      </div> <!-- wrap_footer -->
    </div> <!-- wrap_main -->
  </body>
</html>
```

As my CSS-file is quite big I will only give you the important parts:

```
*{
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-size:12pt;
  color:white; /*003300*/
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

html {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url('/../data/images/03.jpg');
  background-attachment: fixed;
  min-height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

body {
  height:100%;
  width:calc(70% - 2px);
  margin-left: calc((30% - 2px) / 2);
  position: absolute;
}

#wrap_main {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#wrap_content {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: 190px;
  margin-top: calc(1% + 4px);
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  background: #1e1e1e;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#content{
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  margin: 5px auto 10px;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 550px;
  width: 95%;
}
```

If you need more parts, please write so in the comment. I'm sorry if the code is a little messy but I haven't yet cleaned it up...

My problem is, that the #wrap_content and #content can't have a percentage height and I don't know why but it just won't work.

Did I make a mistake somewhere along the way and just don't see it?
What do I need to change, so that the #wrap_main is always as big as it's content? How can I get my #content (or #wrap_content) to adapt to the height of the content (including text and images)?
Do I need to change something in the html-markup?

If you see anything else that I could do better, please advise. I'm still very new to php, html and css but I'll welcome every help I can get. Thanks in advance.

If you want to check out what the page looks like at the moment click [here](http://wikitest.gutknecht-informatik.com). Be aware that not everything is working correctly yet, but if you want to register yourself, you're highly welcome to test it out.

---

EDIT:

I had to change the html-markup a little and adapted the css quite a bit thanks to the idea of William, thanks again:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="<?=$dir_stylesheetFile?>" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

    <title><?=$GuestbookTitle ?></title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="whity_layer">
      <div id="wrap_main">

        <div class="menubar">
          <ul class="menubar_list">

            <a href="http://wikitest.gutknecht-informatik.com"> <!-- Home should always exist,
              other menubar-items can be added in MenubarHandler.php > InternLink or ExternLink -->
              <li class="menubar_item" id="int"><span id="menubar_text">Home</span></li>
            </a>
            <?=$MenuPagesString ?>
          </ul>
          <?=$MenuPagesStringExt ?>
        </div> <!-- menubar -->

        <div id="wrap_header">
          <div id="logoplacer">
            <a href="http://wikitest.gutknecht-informatik.com">
              <img id="img_logo" src="/../data/images/Logo_Guestbook.png" alt="Guestsbook Home"/>
            </a>
          </div> <!-- logoplacer -->

          <div id="profileplacer">
            <?= $ProfilePlacer ?>
          </div> <!-- profileplacer -->
        </div> <!-- wrap_header -->

        <div id="wrap_content">
          <div id="content">
            <div id="content_title">
              <h2><?=$CurrContentTitle ?></h2>
            </div> <!-- content_title -->
            <div id="content_text">
              <?=$CurrContentText ?>
            </div> <!-- content_text -->
          </div> <!-- content -->
        </div> <!-- wrap_content -->
        <div id="wrap_footer">
          © by Kathara
        </div> <!-- wrap_footer -->
      </div> <!-- wrap_main -->
    </div> <!-- whity_layer -->
  </body>
</html>
```

And CSS:

```
*{
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-size:12pt;
  color:white; /*003300*/
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

html {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url('/../data/images/03.jpg');
  background-attachment: fixed;
  min-height:100%;
  width:100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  max-height:auto;
  width:100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

#whity_layer {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
  margin-left: calc((30% - 2px) / 2);
  width: calc(70% - 2px);
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}

#wrap_main {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#wrap_content {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: 190px;
  top: 45px;
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  background: #1e1e1e;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#content{
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  margin: 5px auto 10px;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 95%;
}
```

I'll have yet to decide the min-height of the content-wrapper, but I'll figure it out.

---

EDIT 2

I have to add that at the moment I have a scrollbar on the whity_layer if the content overflows (overflow: auto) which I can't get rid of for the time being... every homebrew attempt I found wouldn't work with my markup... Nowadays it should be easier to hide scrollbars with css in my opinion...

Comment: You could use `position: relative` on the parent, with `position: absolute` and `top: 0`, `bottom: 0` on the child element

Comment: Sorry about that. Didn't read your question well enough, and thought you wanted to use all the available space in the parent element. Mainly because the percentage value in `min-height' specifies the height in relation to the parent container.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but even if I set one divs height to 70% and it's child to 100% it wouldn't work. The #wrap_main displayes a really short div and I can't think of a reason why as the parent's height is set to 100%. The min-height property only seems to work when I use a fixed height....

Comment: I believe there has to be a fixed height on the parent for the percentage height to work.

Comment: damn.... if I set html's and body's height to 100% the content where you need to scroll overflows the body. If I set min-height instead of height other parts don't work anymore... It's like a bug... like I made a mistake somewhere and just can't find it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What do I need to change, so that the #wrap_main is always as big as it's content?

You don't need to use `height` or `min-height` to have the `#wrap_main` always as big as it's content.

> How can I get my #content (or #wrap_content) to adapt to the height of the content (including text and images)?

Just take the `height` and `min-height` out of the CSS

> Do I need to change something in the html-markup?

Not really, just change the CSS.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xr9143fn/) without the `height` and `min-height` on CSS that will adjust it's height according the content.

---

EDIT:

If you just need a whity background, you might consider this:

Create a new `div` `#whity_layer` and make it absolute before all the other `divs`:

```
<body>
  <div id="whity_layer"></div>
  <div id="wrap-main"></div>
  .........
```

Change the CSS to:

```
body {
  position: relative;
}

#whity_layer {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#wrap_main {
  // Remove background
}
```

Comment: I just tried this but if you check out the page now you'll see that the whity background doesn't go to the end of the page.... This is another problem which pops up when I'm changing height and position properties.... what would my #wrap_content need so that it would always have a 70% of the height of #wrap_main?

Comment: Alright, I'm checking it here. Do you need to have the whity background always behind the page, like a layer?

Comment: What if you change the `min-height` of `#content` to `min-height: 100vh;`? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: If you just need a whity layer behing all the text you might want to consider the EDIT on my answer.

Comment: The 100vh is a fixed height, which I'm trying to avoid... :/

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this later as I'll be busy for some time now... I will give the feedback to this proposition of yours ;) Thank you very much so far for helping me out.

Comment: hey William, I've finally tested it, the whity_layer only works with position fixed, which results in an ugly overflow.... with position absolute the whity layer dissappeears even if I set the z-indexes for html, body, and whity_layer so that the layer would be upfront...

Comment: I've changed the css a little.... now i would just have to give wrap_content a fixed min-height and height auto.... Gotta see what's best... Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: No problem Kathara! Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

A time ago i tried to find a css alternative to make my div always as big as it's content, but as long as i remember that was horrible/hard, i'am sorry that i can't really answer you, but if you want to try with another method you can use AngularJs with, for exemple, ng-style so you can give your divs a "dynamic" size.
The rest is all about algorithm :).

Good luck mate :3

Comment: I was thinking of using angular but as I know that not all users might have java activated it wouldn't work and everything would look horrible for them. There must be a way to do this... If I have to change the whole css file or the markup, I'll do it, but I need help in how to do so... :/